# Removing duplicate code in JavaScript; update object passed into function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code snippet that needs to happen three times. Here is the first one:

```
    if (!$scope.subId1) {
        //$scope.subId1 = $scope.userEnteredSubId;
        //cassetteRepository.subId1 = $scope.userEnteredSubId;
        //$scope.userEnteredSubId = '';
        //cassetteRepository.userEnteredSubId = '';
        assignSubId($scope.subId1, cassetteRepository.subId1);
        return;
    }
```

The next two sections of code are a repeat of the code above, but subId1 becomes subId2. And then subId1 becomes subId3.

The commented code is what I'm trying to remove in each snippet, because it's duplicate code. That's why I call `assignSubId()`. However, the values from the caller aren't updated after the method runs:

```
var assignSubId = function(scopeVariable, repositoryVariable) {
    scopeVariable = $scope.userEnteredSubId;
    repositoryVariable = $scope.userEnteredSubId;
    $scope.userEnteredSubId = '';
    cassetteRepository.userEnteredSubId = '';
}
```

Is there a way to do this so I can have one function update the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
    if (!$scope.subId1) {
        assignSubId('subId1');
        return;
    }
```

And

```
var assignSubId = function(subId) {
    $scope[subId] = $scope.userEnteredSubId;
    cassetteRepository[subId]= $scope.userEnteredSubId;
    $scope.userEnteredSubId = '';
    cassetteRepository.userEnteredSubId = '';
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know you could do this. It worked. Thanks!